# English translation of Rav Alfas by Rabbi Isaac Alfassi (RIF)?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, translation

Does anyone know if there is an English translation of Rav Alfasi?

[Here's](https://seforimcenter.com/Rav-Alfas---Rabbi-Yitzchak-Alfasi-2-vol.__p-12540.aspx) the Hebrew version FYI.

If not any suggestions on ways to learn this text with some help with the Hebrew?

Comment: It's not Hebrew, it's the Aramaic of the Talmud.

Comment: alfasi.blogspot.com has translations for a lot of it.

Comment: Oh great thank you!